# Can "R&D" be used as a verb?

Tags: abbreviations

Is "We do R&D" or "We do hardware R&D", where "R&D" is used as a noun, more correct than "We R&D hardware", where "R&D" is used as a verb?

Comment: Expand the initialism: "We research and design hardware". see?

Comment: Turning initialisms into verbs produces some ugly offshoot spellings: "After R&D'ing for the past week, we R&R'd by the seashore at a little cottage that was just right for B&B'ing."

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on what your organization defines "R&D" as.  I would expect ordinarily that it stands for *Research and Development*, in which case "verbing" the acronym would be non-standard usage; but it could equally well stand for "Refine and Deliver" or "Request and Demolish", which would make "we do hardware R&D" the non-standard usage.

In short, if the "R" and "D" are short for a particular part of speech, then use the abbreviation as that part of speech.

Comment: Well, if you chose "R&D" to mean "Research and Develop", it could work. You're basically verbing the noun, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

"We r&d hardware" is hands down the best way to say this. More specifically, if you did something along the lines of:

```
we make
apps

we r&d
hardware
```